# Android - get location from any class

Tags: java, android, static

I have following code. This is a class where I work with Map fragment, but I need to use these methods in other classes.

```
public class FragmentMap extends Fragment {
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location myLocation;

private Location getBestLocation() {
    Location gpslocation     = getLocationByProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Location networkLocation =
            getLocationByProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (gpslocation == null) {
        return networkLocation;
    }
    if (networkLocation == null) {
        return gpslocation;
    }

    long old = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
    boolean gpsIsOld = (gpslocation.getTime() < old);
    boolean networkIsOld = (networkLocation.getTime() < old);

    if (!gpsIsOld) {
        return gpslocation;
    }

    if (!networkIsOld) {
        return networkLocation;
    }

    if (gpslocation.getTime() > networkLocation.getTime()) {
        return gpslocation;
    } else {
        return networkLocation;
    }
}

private Location getLocationByProvider(String provider) {
    Location location = null;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        if ( locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider) ) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d("FragmentMap", "Cannot access Provider " + provider);
    }
    return location;
}
public String getCity(){
    String result = "";
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0){
                result = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

And I need to use it in 3 classes. How can I write it once and use it everywhere, so I don't have to duplicate it in each class. As I understand I should use `public static`. But java doesn't allow me.
I want to see what is the best practice for implementing such kind of thing.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not seem to define a class. Even if you only need static methods, you have to create a class :

```
public class MyClass {
  [...]
}
```

Now, you are using a non-static attribute here :

```
private Location myLocation;
```

So you cannot use it in a static method.

- Either you define this attribute and the method that uses it as static,
- Or you declare both attribute and method as non-static.

Ask yourself if it makes sense to have this attribute as non-static (does it depend of a class instance or should it be shared by all instances?)

If you chose the non-static option, it becomes :

```
public class MyClass {
  //Useless because you are only using a static field of this class.
  //private LocationManager locationManager;

  //Static attributes must be named with UPPER CASE letters
  private static Location MY_LOCATION;

  private static Location getBestLocation() {

  private static Location getLocationByProvider(String provider) {
    ...
  }

  public static String getCity(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This was posted a few seconds before my anwser and it is really a better explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that this is a MapFragment class. I work with map there. I tried to make both variables and methods static, but methods like `getActivity()` cannot be used from a static context.

Comment: I moved all these methods and variables to another class, and now I can access them whereever I want.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

a) You could use a class to access public static methods. Not sure why you are facing an issue with it

b) You can declare an application class in your manifest and add these methods in the application class. The application class can be accessed from all activities and fragments. More details about application class can be found at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

c) You can declare a base class which extends Activity class and add your methods here. Later you can create all your new activities by extending this base class and thereby can access these location retrieving methods. This way even the fragments would be able to access these methods.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a base class...

example:

```
class myLocationClass {

public static Location getBestLocation() {..}
public static Location getLocationProvider() {...}

public static String getCity {...}

}
```

and then use is via the class directly:
`myLocationClass.getBestLocation()` or `myLocationClass.getLocationProvider()` or `myLocationClass.getCity`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of approaching this. The `Application` class is a singleton, so you could have a public method there and access it from wherever you can get a `Context`. A better approach would be to use a Bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) and subscribe to it where you want location updates delivered.